# How does StreamHub do AJAX push through an iFrame?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, push

Basically, how does this work: http://www.stream-hub.com/demo/RealTimeChart/index.html

They are streaming JS through an iframe continuously and the browser window does NOT show the page as "loading". How did they do that? The streaming part is easy, but how do they prevent the browser window from being in a continuous "loading" state?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure this is why, but it seems like they're loading a second `iframe` after the first with `about:blank`.

Comment: Yeah I tried that, too, and it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. The idea is to create the iframe programatically like so:

```
function setupAjax()
{      
  var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");      
  iframe.src = "push.php";
  iframe.style.display = "none";    
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);  
}
```

and then.. `<body onload="setupAjax()">`

Comment: Although this only works in Firefox and IE, not Safari or Chrome.

Comment: Try setting a timeout, that is: `window.onload = function () { setTimeout(setupAjax, 500); }`

Answer (score 1):

Because it is using XMLHttpRequest();. Stream-hub is using long polling method. Surely i'm not enterested with this method because the latency. You can use inline frame.
On index.html

```
function setupAjax()
{      
  var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");      
  iframe.src = "push.php";
  iframe.style.display = "none";    
  document.body.appendChild(iframe);  
}
function update(data)
{
  alert(data);
}
```

On push.php

```
<?php
 for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++ ) {
    echo "<script>window.parent.update('" . i . "')</script>";
    sleep(1);
 }
?>
```

But, don't forget this method still need customization. Commontly problem such as, browser always show loading, to avoid this you can use BEHAVIOUR javascript library to call your setupAjax. This script will call your function after all document has been loaded. Don't forget to checkEscape, and stop button.